# I want to get match pattern from String in java?

Tags: java

I want to get String using match  pattern

**String msg = "Your verification Code is aBc123 This Code Valied for 30 Minutes"**

I Want To Get String or Code From msg String

**String code ="aBc123";**

Comment: is your verification code is fixed lenght?

Comment: yes the code length is fiexd

Comment: Please search for string truncate or for string match function on google

Comment: Do your own homework.  The fact that people gave you an answer and you insist on using regex makes it pretty obvious.

Comment: your code pattern will be same all the time?

Comment: i dont know more bt  "**Code is** aBc123 **This**" Code is and This is fiexd and code is beetween is and this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please do something like this.
I have done it, now you can get the code and minutes as well.
Please have a look and let me know if you have any issues.

```
    String input = "Your verification Code is aBc123 This Code Valied for 30 Minutes";
    Matcher m1 = Pattern.compile("^Your verification Code is (.*) This Code Valied for (.*)$").matcher(input);
    if(m1.find()) {
        String _code = m1.group(1); // aBc123
        String _minutes  = m1.group(2); // 30 Minutes
        System.out.println("Code is : "+_code);
        System.out.println("Minutes is : "+_minutes);

    }
```

Comment: This matcher is for email.
are you need email matcher?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this. its recognising the pattern "code is" and getting the next word as verification code. This will work even if your code length and template is not fixed but the template must have code after the words "code is"

```
String msg = "Your verification Code is aBc123 This Code Valied for 30 Minutes";
String words[] = msg.split(" ");
String code = "";
for(int i =0;i<words.length;i++){
      if(words[i].equalsIgnoreCase("code")&&words[i+1].equalsIgnoreCase("is")){
          code = words[i+2];
          break;
      }
}
```

Comment: thanx bro but i want using pattern or regex

Comment: Then you should mention it in your question

Comment: I want to get match pattern from String in java?